# Why am I getting this: ImportError django.contrib.auth: No module named 'pylibmc'

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, python-3.x, importerror

Attempting to deploy to a virtualenv on Ubuntu 13.10 VPS ... running Python 3.3.2 and I can't figure out how to resolve this.

I tried doing a "pip install pylibmc" but that just blew up (I think because pylibmc does not support Python 3), but I'm not really sure.

Anyhow, can someone explain why I'm getting this message and how I can resolve the issue given my setup?

UPDATE:  Traceback as requested

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/srv/www/test/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Django-1.6.3-py3.3.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/srv/www/test/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Django-1.6.3-py3.3.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/srv/www/test/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Django-1.6.3-py3.3.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/srv/www/test/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Django-1.6.3-py3.3.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 75, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/srv/www/test/venv/lib/python3.3/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1584, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1512, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1584, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 584, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1022, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1003, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_for_loader_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 868, in _load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/srv/www/test/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/south/management/commands/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import django.template.loaders.app_directories
  File "/srv/www/test/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Django-1.6.3-py3.3.egg/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py", line 25, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('ImportError %s: %s' % (app, e.args[0]))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError django.contrib.auth: No module named 'pylibmc'
```

Comment: Can you paste the entire traceback? What is your `CACHES` setting set to?

Comment: I took out the entire CACHES setting.  It used to be:  CACHES = values.CacheURLValue(default="memcached://127.0.0.1:11211")

Comment: "blew up"? You mean pip gave you an error message of some kind, right? Did you read that error message?

Comment: Traceback added to question

Comment: Are you working in a virtual environment? and to clarify, the traceback is a result of "pip install pylibmc"?

Comment: 1. Yes and 2. This traceback is the result of trying to use "django.contrib.auth" without pylibmc installed.  I try to do a "pip install pylibmc" within the virtualenv and I'm presented with a slew of build errors.

Comment: have you installed python-dev?

Comment: yes. and also python3-dev since my project is using python 3.